# PHP HTTP ERROR 500 with active session

Tags: php

Here i have a simple Thank you page "confirm.php" with session but i am getting an HTTP ERROR 500 error when accessed, i need assistance to correct the error

Here is the PHP header for "confirm.php"

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] == 'http'){
    header('location: https://www.example.com/confirm.php');
    exit;
}
        require('includes/session.class.php');
        include 'includes/config.php';
        $session = new session();
        $session->start_session('_RTTLBRZ_', true);
        if(!isset($_SESSION['success'])){
            header('location: ./');

        }


?>
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this?  Have you enabled showing all errors?  Checked the server error logs?  Try searching StackOverflow or Google on "PHP debugging" "PHP show errors" etc. -- you need to learn this.

Comment: I have check the error logs but couldn't find anything worth troubleshooting. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] == 'http') {
    header('location: https://www.example.com/confirm.php');
}

require('includes/session.class.php');
include 'includes/config.php';
start_session();

if(!isset($_SESSION['success'])) {
    header('location: ./');
}
?>
```

Comment: It looks like the only change is, instead of using the session class that the questioner is instantiating, you're using the built-in PHP session management class?

Comment: Please i need assistance, someone assist please.